Objects defined in Java JARs not showing up in Scala files
I am trying to import into a Scala repo a Java library that is not available by remote but provides JARs in its Github commits. For some reason, placing the JARs in project/subproject/lib does not seem to work, and neither does using from "http:/path/to/lib.
No matter what I try to do I can compile, but then have no access to the objects in the JARs.
Any ideas?

Do you have reproduction?

No, it could be local to my machine. But I don't see how.

Note: neither unmanagedJars nor unmanagedSources in build.sbt seem to help

Are you sure the Java JAR contains those classes? You can inspect the JAR yourself.

When you say you can compile: does your code has reference to the classes from the JAR? Meaning the code from the JAR would be present at compilation time but you're having issue at runtime?

@AlexWeinstein Let's try to prepare reproduction. https://github.com/DmytroMitin/so78386477 I created a java jar (sbt javaProj/package), put it into scalaProj/lib and referred a java class in a scala object. The code compiles: https://github.com/DmytroMitin/so78386477/actions/runs/8843468270/job/24283751036 Could you put one of your java jars to scalaProj/lib, refer a java class in a scala object? What happens upon sbt scalaProj/compile? Could you share your problematic jar? Is it a valid zip archive with valid package structure? Does it have valid META-INF/MANIFEST.MF?

The project compiles but there is no ability to import objects in Scala files. I've have tried with Java files but that would be far from ideal.
We have decided the package we were using did not deliver on promises to simplify  the process regarding what we need to build. So we are dropping it and restarting we a new plan.
Thanks for your concern!

"but there is no ability to import objects in Scala files" I still don't understand what does this means.
